# UITableView like contacts Apps edit mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm currently working on an app where we have to collect user details. I would like to build UITable view similar to the contacts app's edit mode view. (ImageView in one column and firstname, lastname and other fields are in other column)

I've looked at different codes and samples..Have no idea how they build it.

[image: Example contacts app editing view]

Answer (score 3):

It is likely a view built something like this...

[image: Figure A]

The green box is where your UIImageView sits. The red box is a UITableView sized to fit alongside the image. The Blue box is another UITableView for the rest of the content. Positioning the blue box will be based on how tall the red box is based on what fields are displayed there.

Comment: I am new to iOS development. Wondering is it possible to have two UITableViews in on UIView. If so, Can you direct me to some code samples?

Comment: It absolutely is possible, try using interface builder, you can literally drag and drop these items on a view controller. Once you do that you setup the outlets and the delegates.

Comment: To be like contacts, I think the image view and the two table views would have to be put in a scroll view, and the table views be set so they don't scroll.

Comment: Darren, good call. That is correct with the layout I proposed.